# How to get NFS working on a Snow-Leopard server?

Tags: mac, nfs

I'm trying, and failing, to set up NFS on an XServe running OS X 10.6. I'm fairly certain the problem is specifically related to the NFS configuration as SMB and AFP are working fine across our network.

I've configured the NFS Service using the Server Admin GUI. The Server Admin GUI says the NFS Service is running, but that nfsd (the nfs server if I'm correct?), portmap, rpc.lockd, and rpc.statd are all "Stopped" - which I feel certain is why I can't mount an NFS share from another machine? How can I get those running so I can ultimately use NFS to mount some directories on a couple of Ubuntu clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instructions did the trick!

http://flamingovic.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/how-to-configure-nfs-on-os-x-10-6-server/

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer (there's a white checkmark to the left of this answer, click it and it will turn green). Thank you.

Comment: @Chris S - Will do as soon as it allows me (1 more day to go)